# De Broglie relationship

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavelength

What wavelength De Broglie relationship represents, if particle's motion is given by its group velocity (which is superposition of waves of many wavelengths)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

de Broglie's relation relates the momentum of a particle to its wavelength. If the particle's wavefunction contains a superposition of different wavelengths, then the particle's state is a superposition of different momenta, and there will be a fundamental uncertainty in the any measurement of momentum.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the electron is being modelled as a wavepacket, then there is no single momentum given by the de Broglie relation. We know this from the Heisenberg uncertainty principle:
$$
\Delta x \Delta p\geq\frac{\hbar}{2}
$$

Which tells that there is uncertainty in the position and the momentum of the wavepacket as can be seen in the diagram below:

[image]

Where the width of the wavepacket is directly related to the uncertainty of the position (on the left) and to the uncertainty of the momentum (on the right).

The momentum given by the group velocity ($p=mv_g$) is the momentum of the entire wavepacket and does not correspond to any meaningful wavelength.